# Help on a probability theory question

Tags: probability, self-study

Let $X \sim U(0,1)$ and let $0 < a < 1$, then find

i) $P(X \le x|X > a)$

ii) $P(X \le x|X < a)$

I have the answers, but I'm wondering if someone can explain the process to me.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! You will have a better chance of getting a helpful answer if you give us some more information. How did you get to the answers you have? You certainly followed some kind of process, so it would be helpful if you could tell us which part is unclear. And perhaps you could add the "self-study" tag so your question is categorized correctly.

Comment: (I just added the self-study tag myself; couldn't do so before since other edits were pending.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward exercise in the application of the *definition* of conditional probability.

$$P\{X \leq x \mid X > a\} 
= \frac{P\left(\{X \leq x\} \cap \{X > a\}\right)}{P\{X > a\}}
= \frac{P\{a < X \leq x\}}{P\{X > a\}}
= \begin{cases}\frac{F_X(x)-F_X(a)}{1-F_X(a)},&x \geq a,\\0,&x<a.\end{cases}$$
The other case is handled similarly.